# I have a large worksheet with many columns. How do ! find specific columns - headers- and their contents and bring them to the beginning of the sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have a large worksheet with many columns. How do I search specific columns return them to the beginning of the same sheet from B1?

I am using this for an automated  weekly task that does not have a consistent format. The columns are not always fixed. Here is an example

Sheet list:

> [image: Screenshot.]

Main sheet:

> [image: Screenshot.]

I would like to search for three individuals and bring them to the beginning of the same sheet from column B like this using macros vba

Same sheet with three columns copied and brought to the beginning of the sheet:

> [image: Screenshot]

I am using Office 365 and Excel 2010 on my personal computer. I will be eventually using this automated sheet on Office 365

I have been adjusting the formula below but can't get it right

```
=INDEX($H2:S10,ROWS($B2:B2),MATCH(B$1,$H1:S1,0))
```

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. Are you trying to do this via VBA or what? What have you tried and what, exactly, is the problem you encountered?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem.

Comment: I am automating a worksheet. and the columns need to be manually arranged because it keeps changing but with the same header names. My boss has suggested that i  find the five specific column i need and copy them to the beginning of the work sheet . I am using excel macros.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1697868/edit) to clarify it. At the very least, include the relevant parts of the code you say you are using and tell us what the problem you have is.

Comment: Looking at the edits you have made, you added a image then removed it. So there is no link to the image. Either re-add it or at least add the macro as @cybernetic.nomad suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is not showing the correct result for subsequent rows because some cell references are wrong. Change your formula to:

=INDEX($H$2:$S$10,ROWS($B$2:B2),MATCH(B$1,$H$1:$S$1,0))

See result using the formula below on a smaller sample than yours

```
=INDEX($H$2:$S$4,ROWS($B$2:B2),MATCH(B$1,$H$1:$S$1,0))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thankyou Reddy. I have adjusted my formula and getting the correct results now!